# RIA Services: A list of Attributes (decoration) for use and what they do?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Quite new to RIA Services but i am progressing... I noticed that some methods are decorated with the QUERY attribute.

I would like to know where i can a list of QUERY attributes with an explanation what they do

Taking QUERY attribute as an example, what if i don't decorate the method on the domainservice?

I tried doing a search for available attributes that i cna use with RIA services.

I presume i can also decorate depending which part of CRUD is being used.

Any help or information is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) you can find all attributes and an explanation of each attribute you can set on methods of a domainservice.

Comment: excellent, thanks!  If my method returns a BOOL on domainService, i.e. its just business logic, no database access stuff. What should i decorate with ??

Comment: @Martin: Use the InvokeAttribute. cause all other attributes/methods operate on the entities that are used by the domainservice.